# Get ListBox item for ContextMenu on item press

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8

I am having issues with using a ContextMenu within a ListBox. One of the items of my ContextMenu is used to pass the name of the item via querystring to another page in my application. As of now I am using the SelectionChanged event of my ListBox to retrieve the name of the item selected, but this requires that the user press and then release the item to register the event. I would like to be able to get the name of the item pressed when the user presses a ListBox item down to access the ContextMenu, without pressing up.

To Note, I have tried using the KeyDown event of the ListBox for this purpose, but it did not work either. What event can I use to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the binding in listbox for listbox item the you can use Tag Property of MenuItem of ContextMenu.
To Bind the tag use

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
<toolkit:ContextMenu Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
<toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="Send" Name="Send" Tag="{Binding Name}" Click="Send_Click_1"/>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

When you click on ContextMenuItem you can access the Tag using

```
var name = ((MenuItem)sender).Tag.ToString();
```

You can access listbox item by using this statement if you are using binding property

```
var listBoxItemName= ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext as ListBoxItemClass;
```

Here, ListBoxItemClass is the name of tha class you used for bind the property.
Try this, hope you get what you want

Comment: Thanks, although I actually need to get the name of the ListBox item when it is pressed and the ContextMenu item I selected. How might I move one step up from getting the name of the ContextMenu item to getting the name of the ListBox item?

Comment: I've suggested you another line of statement by which you can get ListBoxItem when you select ContextMenu item. Do check and notify me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `ListBoxItemClass`. Instead I put `ListBoxItem` although when debugging `listBoxItemName` remains null?

Comment: ListBoxItemClass is the Class that you may using with System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemClass> used to bind ListBox ItemSource. Are you using ObservableCollection or not?

Comment: @Matthew Provide the complete code that you are using to show ListBox that will be more helpful.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. I will have to check this after work, I will get back to you this evening.